# Fractal drawing using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, fractals

I am working on an assignment in which you I have to create a fractal drawing using a given int, I am confused on how to use recursion here.

I am not asking for a full solution, rather maybe just something to get me started in the right direction. Here is what I have so far:

```
def fractal(length, spaces):

    if length == 1:
        print(' ' * int(spaces) + '*')
    else:
        print(fractal(length//2*'*',spaces*' '))
        print(fractal(spaces*' ',length*'*'))
        print(fractal(length//2*'*',spaces+(length//2)*' '))




while True:
    userlength = input('Enter an integer > 0:\n')
    try:
        userlength = int(userlen)
    except:
        continue
    if userlength < 0:
        continue
    else:
        fractal(userlength,userlength)
        break
```

Comment: As @Mark Tolonen points out in his answer, you can literally write lines of code that corresponds to each step in the instructions to define the `fractal()` function. One important point, which I think needs greater emphasis, is making the the function do the printing itself rather than returning a result which needs to be printed by the caller (which might be itself since it's recursive). Another thing to note because it may not be obvious, is that `spaces` should be an integer, not a string.

Comment: @martineau Thank you for the description, but would spaces be set to userlength also? I feel like I am more confused with the directions than with what I am actually supposed to do.

Comment: No it should be hardcoded to zero. When I Implemented it myself doing as @Mark and I suggest, I left determining the value of `userlen` just as you have it, but instead called `fractal(userlen, 0)` — as per the instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best hint I can give is to implement each line of the description exactly as described.

For example, "Create a function def fractal(length,spaces)".  You've done that:

```
def fractal(length,spaces):
```

"If length is 1 print out the number of spaces followed by 1 star.  Note "print" and not "return".

```
    if length == 1:
        print(' ' * spaces + '*')
```

Etc...  If you follow the description exactly, the code writes itself.

One thing that may not be clear from the description is that "print the fractal pattern" means "call the fractal function" with the parameters described.  That's the actual recursion.  The function has to call itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot! So for spaces, would I call that with userlen instead of using the space variable in the while loop?

Comment: @Mike Tolonen I tried revising my code as such but it definitely doesn't seem right, sorry for my lack of understanding, I am very new to this.

Comment: The function doesn’t return anything, so don’t print the function, just call it. The 2nd line of the else is where you print. The function should be called with integers.  Start the recursion with `fractal(userlen,0)` as instructed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate it